# Are films required to show title?

Tags: title

I have seen at least one other movie where the title of the film was not shown until the end of the film. Hunger Games: Mockingjay Pt. 2 is the inspiration for this question. Are films required to show title?

Comment: Required? No. But you'd never see someone not do it.

Comment: @cde Well, [never say never](http://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/36669/has-there-been-a-movie-produced-without-a-title-sequence)...

Comment: So... does that make this a dupe?

Comment: @cde The wording of the question is different but the intent seems to be the same to me.

Comment: Personally, I think it's different. Seem to me that the OP is asking about the *process* of titling a movie and if it's legally\formally required (e.g. by an organization or something).